# Android native music player search intent

Tags: android, android-music-player

In the stock music player in Android 2.1 (at least), the artist, album, and track name of the currently playing track are long clickable, which brings up a context menu "Search for *NN* with:", with links to different apps.

**UPDATE**

I've managed to extract the logs from my own device, doing a search for an artist, and selecting Google Listen to complete the action:

```
03-02 11:59:34.551 I/ActivityManager(   86): Displayed activity com.android.music/.MediaPlaybackActivity: 1758 ms (total 1953 ms)
03-02 11:59:35.691 I/ActivityManager(   86): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras) }
03-02 11:59:36.781 I/ActivityManager(   86): Displayed activity android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity: 1036 ms (total 1036 ms)
03-02 11:59:38.191 I/ActivityManager(   86): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SEARCH flg=0x13000000 cmp=com.google.android.apps.listen/.SearchListActivity (has extras) }
03-02 11:59:38.511 D/Listen  (  491): Request search results for http://lfe-alpo-gm.appspot.com/search?q=Finntroll
```

I will definitely pursue this myself, but this is quite new to me. I'd appreciate assistance here. Does the above mean that as long as I set up `MEDIA_SEARCH` intent as an entry point for an activity, it'll show up in the select list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, `MEDIA_SEARCH` was the right way to go. For reference:

Adding the intent filter is enough to make the application show up in the select list in the media player:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SEARCH" />
```

And then the action can be received as follows:

```
final Intent queryIntent = getIntent();
final String queryAction = queryIntent.getAction();

if (MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_SEARCH.equals(queryAction)) {
    String artist = queryIntent.getStringExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ARTIST);
    ...
}
```

- [INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_SEARCH](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_SEARCH)
- [EXTRA_MEDIA_ARTIST](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_MEDIA_ARTIST)

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks for the tip. But EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE is coming null. I tested on my device (1.5) and Emulator (2.1). However; the other extras are coming fine. 
Did you have a chance to get the Title?

Comment: @Omer: Hi. Whether or not `EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE` has a value depends on how you perform the search (and I guess on how media search is implemented in your music player). in the stock 2.1 player, if you long-click on the album name, you'll search for that album, if you long-click on the title, you'll search for the title. In the former case, `TITLE` will be null. You can also check `MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_FOCUS` to find out what was searched for.

Comment: hi David Hedlund, If don't mind please give some sample related to above post.

Comment: @kiran: I think there's quite a lot of code in the post. Is there anything in particular you need more information on?